# PUT request made with Python requests module has no data

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I am developing an Python REST api and for server side I'm using Django with django-rest-framework. I managed to successfully test my api with AdvancedRestClient in chrome, but I can't get it working with python requests.

My ARC request looks like this:
[image]

And for my test Python request I wrote the following code:

```
import requests
import json

payload = {"TimeStamp": "2016-02-07T13:38:16Z", "DateInserted": "2016-02-07T13:38:18Z", "Value": 17.145, "Sensor": 1}
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Readings"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "966271f8-94a3-4232-95f7-953f3b7989f3"}
r = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

I tried many different things as using `json=` instead of `data=` but my request always seem to have no data content when they arrive to my server side. I searched the web but couldn't find any viable examples of using POST with requests so I'm hoping someone has some first-hand experience in their sleeve to share with me.

**Update:**
The following code now works with django-rest-framework.

```
payload = {"TimeStamp": "2016-02-07T13:38:16Z", "DateInserted": "2016-02-07T13:38:18Z", "Value": 12.123, "Sensor": 1}
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Readings/"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "966271f8-94a3-4232-95f7-953f3b7989f3"}
r = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Your request looks correct to me. Try using `http://httpbin.org/put` to see what you are actually sending.

Comment: Can you add Token before your token?    " Token '966271f8-94a3-4232-95f7-953f3b7989f3'"

Comment: Please add `print json.dumps(json.loads(r.text), indent=4)` and `print r.status_code` to your snipplet and report the result. (Also add the `Token ` in the `Authorization` header.)

Comment: I'm using my own custom Authorization so Token in not needed. I managed to get it working please see comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRF has a trailing space by default. Instead of 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Readings` it should probably be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Readings/` . I would suggest making `Readings`be lowercase as it's easy to forget that it's capitalized

---

The general structure for API tests that I've used is this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APIClient

class TestReadings(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_put(self):

        url = reverse('readings', kwargs={}) # 'readings' here is the named url
        request = self.client.post(url, data={})
```

Comment: I managed to get it working. In order to do so I had to change two things. When I added / to Readings I started to see data coming through but the format was not correct. So the second thing I had to change was to put data= instead of json=. Thank you all for your help.